# How to make InstanceOf work with object from Local Storage

Tags: javascript

I have an object which is an instance of a class.  I then save it to local storage with `JSON.stringify` and then retrieve it with `JSON.Parse`.  However, after retrieving it, it is no longer an instance of the class.  How do I make it so that it is an instance of the class?

In other words, I need `instanceOf` to work correctly after retrieving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor which you loose when you stringify your object.

You can use the JSON data you parse back to re-instantiate your class:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MY_CLASS'));

var myInstance = new myClass(data);
console.log(myInstance instanceof myClass); // should log 'true'
```